# Create view with two keys pointing to the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

There are some similar questions to this posted prior but I cannot extrapolate a solution for my problem from them unfortunately.

I have a Train_Booking table and a Train_Times table. I want to create a view which shows all the train bookings per train conductor. However mine Train_Booking has two Train_Times references in it as: Train_Departure and Train_Arrival fields which hold a unique foreign key pointing to the Train_Times table.

I want to create the view like =

```
CREATE VIEW Train_Bookings_By_Conductor AS SELECT Train_Booking.Train_Booking_ID, Conductor.Conductor_Name, Train_Times.Train_Departure_Date, Train_Times.Train_Arrival_Date
FROM Train_Booking, Conductor, Train_Times
WHERE (Train_Booking.Conductor_ID = Conductor.Conductor_ID) AND (Train_Booking.Train_Outbound_Time_ID = Train_Times.Train_Time_ID)
```

MY PROBLEM is of course that the view displays the Departure date and arrival date as the same.  ADDING the following just breaks the query

```
 AND (Train_Booking.Train_Inbound_Time_ID = Train_Times.Train_Time_ID)
```

Can anyone please shed some light on what to do in this type of scenario? If I've not specified the problem correctly, apologies, I'll rewrite it accordingly! Thanks

**Schemas**

[image]

Comment: So, Train_Times contains (Train_Time_ID) and ONE other field, or two? Looks like it has two? So, outbound_time_ID and inbound_time_ID are both associated with a *pair* of times, not just a single time ?

Comment: Can you add the database schema?

Comment: Train_Times contains Train_Time_ID, Train_Date and Train_Time but for this view I just wanted the date, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can join the Train_Time table twice, instead of once. Imagine, as if you have two copies of the Train_Times table. You join to one for inbound, and you join to the other for outbound. In reality, you only have one such table, but SQL allows you to join multiple times. Each time, you must provide a name that is unique within your query. Suppose we use "T1" and "T2" as the names for the Train_Times table (within our query).

You join to Train_times, calling it "T2" and using the Inbound field to join. Then, we join again; this time calling it "T2" and using the outbound field in the join. You will end up with something like this:

```
SELECT Train_Booking.Train_Booking_ID
  ,T1.Train_Date as Arrival_Time
  ,T2.Train_Date as Departure_Date
FROM Train_Booking
JOIN Train_Times T1  
  on Train_Booking.Train_Inbound_Time_ID  = T1.Train_Time_ID
JOIN Train_Times T2 
  on Train_Booking.Train_Outbound_Time_ID = T2.Train_Time_ID
```

Since you want to reference Conductor, you can join to that as well. The full query will be as follows:

```
SELECT Train_Booking.Train_Booking_ID
  ,Conductor.Conductor_Name
  ,T1.Train_Date as Arrival_Time
  ,T2.Train_Date as Departure_Date
FROM Train_Booking
JOIN Conductor 
  on Train_Booking.Conductor_ID = Conductor.Conductor_ID
JOIN Train_Times T1  
  on Train_Booking.Train_Inbound_Time_ID  = T1.Train_Time_ID
JOIN Train_Times T2 
  on Train_Booking.Train_Outbound_Time_ID = T2.Train_Time_ID
```

A useful tool for such questions is SQlFiddle. Instead of giving table structure in the question, you can make it "live". For instance, here is a live, working example for your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/142a1/4

Comment: I've added the schemas to the question but I think your answer should do the trick, Ill report back.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "JOIN Train_Times AS InboundTime"?

Comment: I've tried to implement that solution but it will not accept the query - could you explain the syntax a little bit?

Comment: I forgot to remove reference to the Conductor. I will fix it in the original, and also add a bit of an explanation that might be helpful in understanding WHY.